# Network connection not linking permanently

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, ethernet

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I've tried everything to keep my ethernet connection working but I'm not having much luck. The only thing that has worked so far is

```
sudo ethtool --change enp1s0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

However, it is not a permanent fix.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `/etc/rc.local`

```
#!/bin/sh -e 
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other 
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

ethtool --change enp1s0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
exit 0
```

Out of curiosity: do you have any idea why you have to force your ethernet settings? Does the other end of the cable not auto-negotiate? Is it a crappy network card?

Comment: I'd recommend adding the "out of curiosity" part as a comment on the question and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/850927/edit) it out of your answer.

Comment: i think that it does not auto-negotiate.but im not an expert on network still learning.